# React Docs Passing Props to a Component - blank screen

Tags: reactjs, components

I am very new to React and trying to practice passing props to a component. I started by creating an external component, but am stuck at import. Can anyone help advise on how to make it work?

I can get the external component to render using the javascript variable syntax {SingleComment}, but not by using the component syntax  - this flags the error:

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or   a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> object

index.js

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import SingleComment from "./SingleComment.js";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ui comments">
      {SingleComment}
      <SingleComment />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

SingleComment.js

```js
import React from "react";

const profile1 = "https://i.imgur.com/1bX5QH6.jpg";

const singleComment = () => {
  return (
    <div className="comment">
      <a href="/" className="avatar">
        <img src={profile1} alt="profile" />
      </a>
      <div className="content">
        <a href="/" className="author">
          Sarah
        </a>
        <div className="metadata">
          <span className="date">Today at 5:00PM</span>
        </div>
        <div className="text">How are you?</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default singleComment();
```

Comment: `export default singleComment`, without the parentheses `()`?

Comment: Components must be upper case letter to start with `SingleComment`. You may enjoy the new Learn section in the beta docs. https://beta.reactjs.org/learn

Comment: Yeah, Anurag is right. Have you gone through the [React official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) ? I think is very important for newcomers to go through this very detailed hands-on tutorials in order to understand the basic concepts and conventions used

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava it was this - thank you!

Comment: @LaloMores yes - I had been working my way through a different tutorial which followed the same pattern as the React documentation, and did try to look through the document to find the error but didn't manage to catch it - thank you for your advice, planning to work through the official examples now.